# UWP Menu XAML Controls

Tags: xaml, windows-10, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to implement a layout like the one in the MSN News app on my app for Windows 10

[image: MSN News navigation bar]

I want to replicate a menu like the one that says "All, Top Stories, US" and such. I have tried ListBox, AppBar and CommandBar and nothing seems to resemble this layout. Which controller should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [`Pivot`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.pivot.aspx) control. You can find out what elements any UWP XAML apps are made of by debugging them with VS and using the Live Visual Tree view.

Comment: *exactly* what I am looking for. Thanks a lot

Comment: And it inspired a blog post... https://blog.onedevjob.com/2016/06/17/snooping-xaml-layouts-of-other-apps/

Comment: Oh even better. You just went ahead and answered all of my future XAML questions.

Comment: One last thing: When I attempt to attach the debugger to any Store app I get an error saying `Unable to locate symbol file 'Microsoft.Msn.News.pdb'` and also this on the output window `'Microsoft.Msn.News.exe' (CLR Native Compilation v1.0): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.3_1.3.24201.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\SharedLibrary.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. Symbol files are required in order to debug.` I have searched around and around for a solution to this but haven't found anything, would you happen to know?

Comment: Interesting... maybe you do need the symbols and I got access to them at some point? I'll need to get back to it later.

Comment: Could you please take a look at this other question I have? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004853/how-to-access-xaml-objects-in-a-different-page