# How to access XAML objects in a different page

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Windows 10 app that has a MainPage.xaml file. In that file I hold the basic menu (hambuger menu) and there is this Frame object that allows me to load new pages when a selection on the menu changes: `<Frame Name="MyFrame"></Frame>`

So when the selection in the `ListBox` changes, there is this event handler that is pretty straightforward: `MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(WeekPage));`

This line of code loads the `Frame` with another XAML page. Now my question is, inside of the `WeekPage.xaml.cs`, can I control where the `MyFrame` object navigates?

In other words, I want to control XAML objects and their properties (buttons, textblocks, listbox) on one XAML file (`MainPage.xaml`) from the code-behind of another XAML file (`WeekPage.xaml.cs`).

I have already tried the following: `<Frame Name="MyFrame" x:FieldModifier="Public"></Frame>` which didn't seem to help at all and setting up `internal static NAMESPACE.MainPage tried;` on `MainPage.xaml.cs` with `MainPage.tried.MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(StoryPage));` on `WeekPage.xaml.cs`(I got that idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632827/access-mainwindow-control-from-a-class-in-a-separate-file)) but I get a `System.NullReferenceException` when I run the program.

**Another example to narrow down on what I am looking for**
There is a `MainPage.xaml` that contains the basic layout for the app (hamburger menu), depending on the item that the user clicks on in the 'ListBox' in for the hamburger menu a new frame is loaded, for example: `WeekPage.xaml`. `WeekPage.xaml` has a `GridView` that, when clicked, should replace the current frame with a new one and clear out any selections on the `ListBox` in `MainPage.xaml`. See code below:

```
private void GridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    // Replacing current frame with new frame
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(StoryPage));
    // TODO: I need to clear out any selection in the ListBox item in MainPage.xaml
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It will only cause more confusion to others who want to edit/review your code. Are you following MVVM pattern? If so you could easily deal this scenario with properties, commands, triggers and obviously INotifyPropertyChanged interface. 

Well if you want to control in xaml.cs  itself then try considering creating a main control and place 2 UserControls within that control as children. Now there is a relationship and you could access the parent like `Application.Current.MainWindow`.

Comment: I have no set way to approach this issue and I am trying to implement a solution in the best way possible, which is why I posted this question. Your proposal is a bit confusing and I would be very grateful if you could provide a bit more detail into your approach.

Comment: At best, the question is too broad. You need to include a good [mcve] showing what you've tried, with a precise explanation of what specifically you're having trouble with. That said, as the first comment above alludes to, you seem to be asking the wrong question. Views (e.g. pages) ideally shouldn't even access _themselves_, never mind other views. Elements in a view should correspond to view _models_; if you want input in one view to affect what's displayed in another view, there should be a model in between that mediates that.

Comment: Could you expand a bit on that model? My "broadness" is because I just ran into this issue and, as any other thing, I have to ask to learn. I just learned, for example, that I can use `Frame.Navigate(typeof(StoryPage));` to replace the current frame with another page, but I am still in the search for how to implement this "model" that allows me to control XAML objects between different pages. As far as the question not being precise, I honestly can't see it being more specific, my example is right there and it discusses frames. I can add another one if you would like.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I added one more example to help you understand a specific thing that I am trying to accomplish with an explanation and a code example. I hope this clears the discussion into something more specific. Any ideas that you have about approaching this issue please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re not aware of the MVVM approach, please read more on it. In MVVM approach, each view will be bound to a view model. Ie The data in view will be bound to view model properties.
For eg : Say you have a text box, you bind the **Text** property of it to a **string** property in its corresponding view model.

In your scenario we can have  a MainView consisting of 2 subviews.

```
MainWindow.xaml - MainWindowViewModel
SubView1.xaml - SubView1VM
SubView2.xaml - SubView2VM
```

MainView will consist of 2 sub views in xaml and also 2 view models of subviews in main view model.
You can also have commands within each sub viewmodel corresponding to button clicks or any such events.

You could handle these commands in the MainWindowViewModel. Suppose in your view 2 you have a button that transits to view 1 as well as change all the textbox values in view 1.
Handle the button command in MainWindowViewModel and change the SubView1VM properties from within the MainVM.

Hope you got the idea of MVVM. Your requirement is easily achievable using MVVM. MVVM is more coder friendly and helps to separate the view data from model.

**For anyone looking to get started on MVVM**
https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/building-blocks-universal-windows-platform-16064?l=5V1wM0kDC_2606218949

Comment: Thank you for providing me with this idea. MVVM is definitively new to me but I will surely look into it for a solution to my issue. If any other inquiries show up I will post them in this comment thread. Once again, thanks!

Comment: Welcome. As @Peter Duniho said, your question was too broad to be answered. Anyways give it a try and revert if you face any issues. 
Anyways, if you’re satisfied with the answer, please feel free to mark it as the answer so that it will be helpful for others in future.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I added a small tutorial video URL as reference to anyone that finds this question, please accept changes for me to mark as response. @ViVi